# PHP: How to attach existing file from server and send email

Tags: php, email-attachments

If file already exist in server, I can attach one file at a time from the below code.

May i know how to attach two to three file at a time and send mail

Help me friends im struggling for the solution around four days.

```
$email_to = "$email"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from = "online@tryteksolutions.co.in"; // The email you are sending from (example)
$email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
$fileatt = "files/TRYTEK.rar" // Path to the file (example)
$fileatt_type = "application/x-rar-compressed"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = "download.rar"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers="From: $email_from"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

Comment: why do you try to reinvent the wheel?
why don't you use a ready class that handles everything? take a look at swiftmaler for example. Easy to use. http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: @Peehaa give me solution for my answer

Comment: the above code send only one attachment at a time but i want to send two file

Comment: @PeeHaa for the above question

Comment: Friends give me solution for my answer dont give negative points

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using to send multiple attachments, I hope this helps you too. You actually need to use a loop at attach multiple files.

```
    $files = array("file1.pdf","file2.pdf");
    $body = "email in html form";

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "e-mail id of person you are sending to";
    $from = "your e-mail id";
    $subject = "email subject";
    $message = html_entity_decode($body);
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

   // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"   {$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++) {
        $file = fopen($files[$x], "rb");
        $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    // send

    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($ok) {
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
    }
```

Comment: im sending files which is already exist on the server i want to send existing file via mail

Comment: yes i understand, you need to add the names of files in this code `$files = array("file1.pdf","file2.pdf");` If there is a folder on your server which has files then use this `$files = array("foldername/file1.pdf","foldername/file2.pdf");`